# Crontab не может запустить geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, cron, crontab

Есть файл python

```
#!/usr/bin/ python
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
with Display(visible=False, size=(1200, 1500)):
    firefox_dir = "/usr/bin/selenium/webdriver/firefox"
    ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=firefox_dir)
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(ff_profile)
    browser.get("http://www.python.org")
    print browser.title
    browser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Есть задача в кроне 
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/python /var/www/test/test.py > /tmp/listener_new.log 2>&1

Бьет ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/test/test.py", line 14, in <module>
if __name__ == "__main__":main()
File "/var/www/test/test.py", line 9, in main
browser = webdriver.Firefox(ff_profile)
File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Подскажите, люди добрые, в чем может быть ошибка? Из терминала скрипт запускается и отрабатывает.

Comment: *"'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH."*  -- в какой директории geckodriver лежит? (`shutil.which('geckodriver')`) Находится ли она в `os.environ['PATH']`? (при запуске из cron)

Comment: @jfs , А что это за os.environ['PATH']? Как выполнить проверку, не подскажите?

Comment: `print(os.environ['PATH'])` в ваш скрипт добавьте когда он из cron запускается (если не знаете что такое $PATH переменная окружения, задайте отдельный вопрос). Сравните с директорией показываемой `python -с "import shutil; print(shutil.which('geckodriver'))"` командой в терминале.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, перенесла geckodriver в /usr/bin и все заработало. :)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри sys.path у себя и поставь нужные переменные $PATH при запуска в кроне. 
Попробуй выполни у себя в терминале

```
which geckodriver
```

Например у меня

```
which chromedriver 
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Этот путь нужно поставить в cron